# iterate over multiprocessing queue

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
from  netmiko import ConnectHandler
from netmiko.ssh_exception import AuthenticationException,NetMikoTimeoutException
import getpass
import csv
import time
from pprint import pprint
import multiprocessing

from multiprocessing import Manager


def config_one_device(device,output_q):
    print (f"start executing  function on device  {device['host']}")
    try:
        connection=ConnectHandler(**device)
        connection.config_mode()
        config=connection.send_command("set system services netconf ssh")
        connection.commit(and_quit=True)
        output_q.put({device["host"]:connection.send_command("show config system services ")})
        connection.disconnect()

    except NetMikoTimeoutException as timout_error:
        print(f"not able to reach device {device['host']} , make sure the host address is correct")
        print(timout_error)
    except AuthenticationException as auth_error :
        print(f"wrong credentials to connect to{device['host']} ")
        print(auth_error)
    except Exception as unknow_error:
        print(unknow_error)
    else :
        print(f"connection to device{device['host']} is sucessfull")

    
def config_all_devices(devices):
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        pool_tuple=[(dev, output_q) for dev in devices]
        pool.starmap(config_one_device,pool_tuple)

if __name__=="__main__":
    start_time=time.perf_counter()

    

    username1=input("please enter the username to connect to cisco devices: ")
    if not username1:
        raise Exception("you did not enter a username")
        

    password1=getpass.getpass(prompt=" enter the password to connect to cisco devices")
    assert (password1) ,"you did not enter a password"

    with open ("devices.csv" ,"r") as f:
        csv_reader=csv.reader(f,delimiter=";")
        devices=[{ "host" :row[0],"port":row[1],"device_type": "juniper_junos","username":username1, "password": password1} for row in csv_reader if row[1]!="port"]
    
    m=Manager()
    output_q=m.Queue()
    config_all_devices(devices)
    output_q.put("done")
    while True:
        item=output_q.get()
        print(item)
        if item== "done":
            break

    end_time=time.perf_counter()
    print(f"it took {end_time - start_time} for srcipt to excute")
```

i'm trying to connect to multiple network device and push some config then pull some info from each device and put it in a multiprocessing queue.
the issue is that i'm able to iterate though thee queue but the program get stuck so i did add a string "done" at the end of the queue and match "done" to make it stop. however i don't want to print the "done" item of the queue.
is there any proper way to iterate thought this queue without  matching on a specific  element to make it stop.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are printing the item you just retrieved from the output queue with `get` *before* you are testing whether it is your *sentinel* 'done', you could simply check for the sentinel and break *before* doing the `print` statement:

```py
    while True:
        if item== "done":
            break
        item=output_q.get()
        print(item)
```

But there is no need to use a 'done' sentinel at all given that you are doing the `get` of all the items only after all the submitted tasks have completed and therefore all the items that will ever be on the queue are already there. Just use a *non-blocking* `get` call and test for the `queue.Empty` excepton:

```py
    try:
        while True:
            item = q.get(block=False) # or q.get_nowait()
            print(item)
    except Empty:
        pass
```